# how to avoid this error (Error : display Surface quit ) when rendering open-AIgym?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, render, reinforcement-learning, openai-gym

I am trying to solve the mountain car problem in AI gym, but when I use `env. render()`it works the first time, but when I try to render the simulation again after 2000 runs it gives the below error ( error: display Surface quit). How can I avoid this error?

I am using windows, and I am running the code on a jupyter notebook.

```
import gym
import numpy as np 
import sys

#Create gym environment.
discount = 0.95
Learning_rate = 0.01
episodes = 25000
SHOW_EVERY = 2000
    
env = gym.make('MountainCar-v0')

discrete_os_size = [20] *len(env.observation_space.high)
discrete_os_win_size = (env.observation_space.high - env.observation_space.low)/ discrete_os_size
q_table = np.random.uniform(low=-2, high=0, size=(discrete_os_size + [env.action_space.n]))

# convert continuous state to discrete state 
def get_discrete_state(state):
    discrete_State = (state - env.observation_space.low) / discrete_os_win_size
    return tuple(discrete_State.astype(int))




for episode in range(episodes):
    
    if episode % SHOW_EVERY == 0:
        render = True
        print(episode)
    else:
        render = False

    ds = get_discrete_state(env.reset())
    done = False
    while not done:
        action = np.argmax(q_table[ds])
        new_state, reward, done, _ = env.step(action)
        new_discrete_state = get_discrete_state(new_state)
        
        if episode % SHOW_EVERY == 0:
            env.render()


        if not done:
            max_future_q = np.max(q_table[new_discrete_state])
            current_q_value = q_table[ds + (action, )]
            new_q = (1-Learning_rate) * current_q_value + Learning_rate * (reward + 
                 discount * max_future_q )
            q_table[ds + (action, )] = new_q

        elif new_state[0] >= env.goal_position:
            q_table[ds + (action, )] = 0

        ds = new_discrete_state
        
   

    env.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem, cuz when you call env.close() it closes the environment so in order run it again you have to make a new environment. Just comment env.close() if you want to run the same environment again.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).